# Python - Create total sum of items per person from a csv file

Tags: python, csv

I have an excel file that has 3 columns like below.

```
Person    Item        Quantity

John      TV          4
John      Book        14
John      Book        8
John      Chair       8
Bob       TV          16
Bob       Pen         7
Bob       Keyboard    8
Bob       Pen         7
```

I need to generate the total sum of each Item per Person. Printing out the result would look like this:

```
John, TV, 4
John, Book, 22
John, Chair, 8

Bob, TV, 16
Bob, Keyboard, 8
Bob, Pen, 14
```

I don't want the total sum of items it needs to be per person.

Currently i am reading in the CSV file as a list

```
import csv 

csvfile = open('book1.csv', 'r')

data = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in data:
```

How can i create the sum of items based on each person?

Comment: Show us your attempt to solve this problem.

Comment: i am new to Python i'm not familiar with the data-types. My intuition is telling me to:
loop through each row in the csv file, create X number of lists based on how many unique people are in the table. Then add pairs of (item, quatity) to each list. Then once the loop is finished you can sum up each item in each list because they will be unique to that person

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a Counter

```py
from collections import Counter
c = Counter()

for row in data:
    try:
        name, what, cnt = row
    except ValueError: # Empty/broken line
        continue
    try:
        cnt = int(cnt)
    except ValueError: # Invalid quantity
        continue
    c[(name, what)] += cnt

for k in sorted(c):
    print "%s, %s, %d" % (k + (c[k], ))
```

Result:

```
Bob, Keyboard, 8
Bob, Pen, 14
Bob, TV, 16
John, Book, 22
John, Chair, 8
John, TV, 4
```

Comment: Python is complaining about empty and broken lines in your data. I'll add some error handling.

Comment: thank you! How do i view the result as you displayed in the bottom section? What do i call print on?

Answer (score 2):

you can use also [pandas groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html)

```
import pandas as pd
s = read_excell('/path/to/excell')
s.groupby(level=['Person', 'Item']).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the power of [SQLite](https://sqlite.org/) for this:

Input:

```
John,TV,4
John,Book,14
John,Book,8
John,Chair,8
Bob,TV,16
Bob,Pen,7
Bob,Keyboard,8
Bob,Pen,7
```

Using the [SQLite client](https://sqlite.org/cli.html):

```
sqlite> drop table so;
sqlite> create table so (person text, item text, quantity integer);
sqlite> .mode csv
sqlite> .import so.csv so
sqlite> select person, item, sum(quantity) from so group by person, item;
Bob,Keyboard,8
Bob,Pen,14
Bob,TV,16
John,Book,22
John,Chair,8
John,TV,4
```

Since Python includes   by default, the same could be done from Python.

Answer (score 0):

if you would want to keep it separated into classes, below is a try:-

```
import csv

class Items(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.Name = None
        self.Value = 0

    def __init__(self, itm, val):
        self.Name = itm
        self.Value = int(val)


class People(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.Name = None
        self.ItemList = []

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.Name = name
        self.ItemList = []

    def add_item(self, item, value):
        found_item = False
        if self.ItemList is not None:
            for each_item in self.ItemList:
                if each_item.Name == item:
                    found_item = True
                    each_item.Value += int(value)
            if found_item is False:
                self.ItemList.append(Items(item, value))
        else:
            self.ItemList.append(Items(item, value))

    def get_item(self):
        if self.ItemList is not None:
            for each_item in self.ItemList:
                print(self.Name, ",", each_item.Name, ",", each_item.Value)


csvfile = open('book1.csv', 'r')

data = csv.reader(csvfile)

people_list = []

for row in data:
    print(row)
    found_person = False
    if len(people_list) != 0:
        for each_person in people_list:
            if each_person.Name == row[0]:
                found_person = True
                each_person.add_item(item=row[1], value=row[2])
        if found_person is False:
            new_person = People(row[0])
            new_person.add_item(item=row[1], value=row[2])
            people_list.append(new_person)
    else:
        new_person = People(row[0])
        new_person.add_item(item=row[1], value=row[2])
        people_list.append(new_person)

for each_person in people_list:
    each_person.get_item()
```

the output is:

```
John , TV , 4
John , Book , 22
John , Chair , 8
Bob , TV , 16
Bob , Pen , 14
Bob , Keyboard , 8
```

Answer (score 0):

This is some rough pseudocode (aka not guaranteed to work). But basically, find the column index of the name and quantity and keep a record of each owner in a dictionary.

```
item_ownership_overview = {}

header, data = data[0], data[0:]
name_index = header.index("name")
quantity_index = header.index("quantity")

for row in data:
owner = row[name_index] 
quantity = row[quantity_index]

if owner in item_ownership_overview:
   item_ownership_overview[owner] += quantity
else:
   item_ownership_overview[owner] = quantity
```